# Why is my Proxy wrapping a Map's function calls throwing TypeError?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
var cache = new Proxy(new Map(), {
    apply: function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
        console.log('hello world!');
    }
});

cache.set('foo', 'bar');
```

As far as I can tell this *should* result in `hello world!` being logged to the console and the Map's `foo` key not being set. However, when I run this, it throws:

```
TypeError: Method Map.prototype.set called on incompatible receiver [object Object]
    at Proxy.set (native)
    at repl:1:7
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:23:33)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:340:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:537:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:189:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:238:10)
```

I've Googled and gone over all the MDN Proxy docs several times, and I can't wrap my head around why this isn't working.

Any ideas? I'm on Node.js 7.5.0.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Can you just create a subclass of `Map`?  For example, you could just override `.set()` in a subclass.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah, overriding `.set` was my original idea. the only reason I'm using Proxy is because this project is educational and I wanted to try out the new shiny :D

Comment: The `apply` trap is for function objects being called, and won't ever work on a `Map` object (which is not callable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply` traps calling (if you were proxying a function), not method calls (which are just property access, a call, and some `this` shenanigans). You could supply `get` and return a function instead:

```
var cache = new Proxy(new Map(), {
    get(target, property, receiver) {
        return function () {
            console.log('hello world!');
        };
    }
});
```

I don’t suppose you’re just trying to override parts of `Map`, though? You can inherit from its prototype in that case (this is a much better option than the proxy if it’s an option at all):

```
class Cache extends Map {
    set(key, value) {
        console.log('hello world!');
    }
}

const cache = new Cache();
```

Comment: ooooohhhh. thank you! this was really irking me. as I said below OP I'm just trying to override `.set` - I know Proxy is overkill but it's an educational project so I decided to use it "because" :)