# How to properly extend ES6 Map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I have a simple case: a ES6 `Map`, and I need to add custom `get()` and `set()` to it.

But `Map` is a built-in object, so I'm not sure whether there would be any caveats in doing so. I've tried to search whether it is correct to subclass a `Map`, and got inconsistent results: it is unclear whether it's allowed by specification, what browser/node.js versions support it, and what side-effects are possible (and what to cover with tests).

As I understand, there are three main approaches to extend `Map` functionality:

1. **Subclass it.** That I've done, and it *seems* like it works.

```js
class CustomMap extends Map{
    get(key){
        return super.get(key);
    }
    set(key, value){
        return super.set(key, value);
    }
}
```

Problem with it: a lot of articles on the Internet state that you can run into troubles with extending built-in objects. Most are early 2016, and now is late 2017, testing in Chrome 61. Maybe now it is a safe and supported way of doing it?

2. **Make a wrapper object**

```js
const Wrapper = function(){
    this._map = new Map();
    this.get = (key) => {return this._map.get(key);}
    this.set = (key, value) => {this._map.set(key, value);}
    ... everything else
}
```

The least elegant solution, as I need to implement not just `get` and `set`, but *all* of Map functionality. Also, `Wrapper` is not an instance of `Map`.

3. **Use ES6 Proxy**

```js
const ProxyMap = function(){
    return new Proxy(new Map(), {
        get(target, key){
            return target.get(key)
        }
        set(target, key, value){
            target.set(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

As with extending a class, it is unadvisable to apply `Proxy` to some built-in types. But again, a lot of time passed since introducing the `Proxy` specifications; maybe now `Map` could by proxied in modern browsers?

So, the question is: what way of extending a `Map` is a correct and robust way in 2017?

Comment: *"a lot of articles on the Internet state that you can run into troubles with extending built-in objects"* Maybe you are referring to the fact that extending built-in objects isn't well supported in Babel because ES5 doesn't support it.

Comment: *someone on the internet* is as helpful as *someone told me yesterday to not eat chocolate* , this may not mean that chocolate is not delicious

Comment: The warnings about *extending built-in objects* are about adding stuff to `Array.prototype`, `Object.prototype` etc for other built-in objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> It is unclear whether it's allowed by specification

It is. Since ES6, all builtin types are extensible using `class` syntax

> It is unclear what browser/node.js versions support it

They need to support ES6 classes and `Map` natively. Using a transpiler will usually break it.

> 1) Subclass it. That I've done, and it seems like it works.

Yes, that is the correct approach.

> a lot of articles on the Internet state that you can run into troubles with extending built-in objects. Most are early 2016, and now is late 2017, testing in Chrome 61.

I dunno, the major reference http://perfectionkills.com/extending-native-builtins/ is from 2011. And these articles meant a different thing by "extending builtins": amending their prototype objects with custom objects, e.g. `Map.prototype.getWithDefault = function(…) { … };`. They do not refer to `class … extends …`.

> Make a wrapper object

This should be fine as well. I don't think you necessarily need your instances to be `instanceof Map`, if you do you'd have to follow the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Not all "extensions" of a key-value collection would fit that.

> 3) Use ES6 Proxy - it is unadvisable to apply Proxy to some built-in types.

Indeed, [this doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43236329/1048572) or is at least cumbersome.

Comment: _Not all "extensions" of a key-value collection would fit that._ What do you mean with "extensions"? And are k/v collections meant as dictionaries (e.g. of type `Map {Number: Boolean}`)?

Comment: @ftor Yes, dictionaries/maps/hashes/accociative-arrays/whatever-you-wanna-call-them. I could imagine implementations of customisations that don't follow the LSP. E.g. a multi-map should not be a subclass of map.

Comment: please show example of how to

Comment: @AlexanderMills Of how to do what?

Answer (score 4):

You can use your first approach using a class which extends `Map`.

For example, the below is an implementation of queues (FIFO structures) extending `Map`, which allows you to manage queues in JavaScript with a O(1) time complexity for both insertions and removals:

```js
class MyQueue extends Map {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.insertionIndex = 0;
    this.removalIndex = 0;
  }

  queue(element) {
    this.set(this.insertionIndex, element);
    this.insertionIndex++;
  }

  dequeue() {
    const el = this.get(this.removalIndex);
    this.delete(this.removalIndex);
    if (el) {
      this.removalIndex++;
    }
    return el;
  }
}

const q = new MyQueue();
q.queue(1);
q.queue(2);
console.log(q.dequeue());
console.log(q.dequeue());
q.queue(3);
console.log(q.dequeue());
console.log(q.dequeue()); // now is empty so dequeue will return undefined with no errors
q.queue(4);
console.log(q.dequeue());
```

Comment: Why `if (el)`? That prevents the queue from storing falsy values

Answer (score 3):

The first one is the way to go. class syntax is supported with ES6, as well as Maps and extending Maps is part of this initial defininition too. So every system that supports Maps supports the first method, and the second and the third are just ugly ( concerning performance etc.)

Answer (score -3):

What about overriding the methods?

```
m = new Map()
m.set('x', 2)
m.get('x')
=> 2
Map.prototype.get = (x) => 'lalala'
m.get('x')
=> lalala
```

Comment: Overriding native objects has [always been frowned upon](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-native-builtins/). It's breaking functionality for any other code that uses the built-in object and can break in the future with spec changes. The reason why `.includes()` is called that instead of `.contains()` is due to [the MooTools library which modified native arrays with their own version of `.contains()`](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/having-a-non-enumerable-array-prototype-contains-may-not-be-web-compatible) which was incompatible. So the official spec was changed because of it.