# Why is Set Incompatible with Proxy?

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

JavaScript [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) appears to be entirely incompatible with JavaScript [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), attempting to `Proxy()` a `Set()`

```
var p = new Proxy(new Set(), {
  add(target, val, receiver) {
    console.log('in add: ', target, val, receiver)
  }
})
p.add(55)
```

results in a VMError:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Method Set.prototype.add called on incompatible receiver [object Object]
    at Proxy.add (native)
    at <anonymous>:1:3
```

In fact, proxying a `Set()` in any way breaks it categorically - even if our proxy handler does nothing at all! Compare `p = new Proxy({}, {})` vs `p = new Proxy(new Set(), {})`. (This applies both in Firefox (52.0.2) and Chromium (57.0.2987.133).)

I can't seem to find a credible reference or documentation for this, why cannot JavaScript `Proxy` a `Set` object and why is it hitting a VM Error?

Comment: There is no `add` trap in proxies. It looks like you're looking for a subclass, not a proxy (which is not a `Set` and can't be used with Set methods)

Comment: @Bergi Where do you see this answered? The answer for Map does not apply to Set and neither does it explain why an empty handler will break a Set Proxy. As for the lack of a trap: is this documented anywhere? Why does an empty trap `{}` cause VMErrors for a Set Proxy?

Comment: No, I'm not looking for a subclass, please read the question before closing it as duplicate next time...

Comment: The explanation does apply, `Map`s and `Set`s work alike. And really, it *does* look like you're looking to intercept `add` method calls, for which subclasses are the easiest solution.

Comment: I'm asked 2 questions which are clearly stated in my question (neither of which are answered in the linked to 'duplicate' questions): Where is it documented (or is it) that `Proxy` is incompatible with `Set`? Why does it cause a VMError even on an *empty handler*? No where in my question does it ask "how do I intercept add calls".

Comment: Well, the declaration of the `add` function certainly implies that :-) That's as good as an empty [proxy handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler) object.

Comment: The duplicate explains that the method "*is called with `this` set to the proxy, not the `Map` — which `Map` [methods don't] like.*". See also the explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29926193/1048572)

Comment: > Well, the declaration of the add function certainly implies that - No it doesn't it illustrates that the `add` fails to trap calls to Proxy - but it doesn't explain why and neither does the documentation which you linked to. In fact the documentation explicitly states *All traps are optional. If a trap has not been defined, the default behavior is to forward the operation to the target.* - which is the expected behavior we see with e.g.  `p = new Proxy({}, { doesNotCaptureAnything() { }})` (as you say equivalent to an empty-handler).

Comment: On the other-hand none of that explains why `p = new Proxy(new Set(), {})` (have you actually tried running it?) completely breaks the target, that is explicitly contradicting the docs the *forward the operation to the target* fails. So with that established I would expect/hope (as someone potentially surprised by this) to be able to google and see an Stackoverflow answer with a link say to the ES5/ES6 spec, or otherwise explaining how it happens? (Is it just a coincidental implementation detail that *happens* to coincide in Node, Firefox, Chrome ?)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I am attempting to `Proxy()` a `Set()`

However, you haven't used any of the [available traps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler) - there is no `add` one. All that you can intercept in the call `p.add(55)` is the *property access* to `.add` on the proxy, which goes through the `get` trap and returns a function.

If you want to intercept calls to the `add` method, you don't need a proxy at all, better (subclass and) overwrite that method similar to how `.set` was overridden [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42381180/1048572) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43236808/1048572) for `Map`.

> proxying a `Set()` in any way breaks it categorically

Yes, because the proxy is not a `Set` any more.

```
var s = new Set([42]);
var p = new Proxy(s, {});
s.has(42) // true
console.log(s === p) // false
p.has.call(s, 42) // true
p.has(42) // exception - calls `has` on `p`, not on `s`
```

Calling `Set` methods on objects that are no True Sets does throw an exception (which e.g. [can be used for detecting them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29926193/1048572)). For your particular case, see [ECMAScript 6 §23.2.3.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-set.prototype.add):

> "*If `S` does not have a `[[SetData]]` internal slot, throw a `TypeError` exception.*"

And indeed, `p` is a proxy (which does have the [internal Proxy methods and slots](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots), especially `[[ProxyHandler]]` and `[[ProxyTarget]]`) instead of a set like `s` with its `[[SetData]]` internal slot.

You reasonably were expecting that "*if a trap has not been defined, the default behavior is to forward the operation to the target*", however that only applies to standard behaviours like property access, and not the internal slots of exotic objects.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer.