# How to combine Set and Map function by proxy?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Any one know how to combine map and set by proxy, like this :

```
var a=new Set();
b=proxy(a,handler);
b.add(1);
b.add(1);
b.set('test1','testing');
console.log(b);//{1,'test1'=>'testing'}
```

Any one know how to do ,thanks

Comment: And what kind of object `{1,'test1':'testing'}` is?

Comment: You have syntax errors. May you edit your question to make sure the code is a [mcve]?

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have updated the question.

Comment: Why not only using Map? (and using set with null as second parameter when the intention is only inserting a unique key, as in Set)

Comment: Using a proxy makes no sense and only [complicates everything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43927933/1048572). What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?