# How do I apply `get` Proxy on `window.location` in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using *Chrome 60*. I've just tried to apply a `get` *Proxy* on `window.location`.

It worked for the first two reference, however, then it failed with `Illegal invocation` error:

```
location = new Proxy(location, {
    get: (target, name) => {
        console.log(name, target, "PROX");
        return target[name];
    }
});
```

The error messages were:

> VM3495:3 Symbol(Symbol.toPrimitive) Location {…} "PROX"
>
> VM3495:3 toString Location {…} PROX
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation at :1:10

1. Why did it throw the error?
2. How do I apply `get` Proxy on `window.location` in Javascript?

Comment: I'm not sure whether `location` can be assigned to.

Comment: @Bergi It can’t! The code was from my try to do so, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why did it throw the error?

It's for the same reason [why proxies are incompatible with `Set`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927933/why-is-set-incompatible-with-proxy) or [with `Map`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43236329/1048572): They are native objects, and their methods (like `toString` in your example) expect to be called on exactly such a native object with the respective internal slots, not a proxy.

> How do I apply get Proxy on `window.location` in Javascript?

You need to bind all methods that the `get` traps intercepts to the target:

```
new Proxy(location, {
    get: (target, name) => {
        console.log(name, target, "PROX");
        return typeof target[name] == "function"
          ? target[name].bind(target)
          : target[name];
    }
});
```

However, that still doesn't change that you cannot replace the `window.location` global with your own implementation. It's a non-configurable property, and assigning to it will cause a navigation not write to the property.