# Exceeding maximum stack call size using Proxies

Tags: javascript, debugging, ecmascript-6, stack, proxies

I'm trying to make a proxy for a certain object to check if the properties are either accessed or modified then `console.log` the property that was changed. I'm fairly new to JavaScript so I'm not sure what could be causing the stack to overflow. I think it's due to a weird scope issue with `console.log` but I'm not sure. This is what my handler looks like

```
var handler = {
    set: function(obj, prop, value) {
         console.log(prop);
         obj[prop] = value;
    }
    get: function(obj, prop, receiver) {
          if (typeof prop !== 'symbol') console.log(prop);
          return obj[receiver];
    }
};
```

I'm assigning the handler to a `CanvasRenderingContext2D` element named `ctx` using this line.

```
 watchedCtx = new Proxy(ctx, handler);
```

I added the extra check to the get property method because I was receiving a lot of `Symbol` primitives from get method and I thought that was the issue so I attempted to filter them out. Has anyone else ever experience this issue or have any idea what may be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the typo is `obj[receiver]`, which should be `obj[prop]`. `receiver` is an object (usually your proxy itself), so by doing `obj[receiver]`, you're converting `receiver` into string, which requires calls to `get`, which then triggers the infinite recursion that you are seeing. That will resolve your issue, but as you might be wondering now, what's `receiver` for then?

In this case, `receiver` is critical for the correct operation of your proxy. The easiest way to deal with that if you're writing a proxy, you should be using the methods from `Reflect` to ensure that you actually preserve the behavior properly.

```
var handler = {
  set: function(obj, prop, value, receiver) {
    console.log(prop);

    return Reflect.set(obj, prop, value, receiver);
  }
  get: function(obj, prop, receiver) {
    if (typeof prop !== 'symbol') console.log(prop);

    return Reflect.get(obj, prop, receiver);
  }
};
```

The `Reflect` methods perform the exact original behavior that a proxy *would* have performed, so by using them, you avoid the dangers of not implementing them correctly yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that solved that issue. Now I'm getting a `TypeError: Illegal Invocation`

Comment: That would require more changes to your code. I'd recommend reading over something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927933/why-is-set-incompatible-with-proxy The short of it is that you're calling a function from `CanvasRenderingContext2D` but passing it a proxy instead of a real canvas, which causes an error, so you'd have to `.bind` or wrap the functions such that they are passed the correct context.